# Multiple image upload and write to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

I've managed to get a photo to be uploaded to the server and then written to the database thanks to quite a bit of help but I need to be able to upload three files and each needs to be written to the database accordingly. So at the moment only photo1 is being uploaded and written, I'd like to create another form input for photo2 and 3 and have them also written and uploaded. Sorry I'm almost a complete beginner with php, any help will be hugely appreciated! thanks in advance.

```
<?php


    session_start();

    include_once('../php/connection.php');

    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

        if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_FILES['photo1'])) {

            $title    = $_POST['title'];
            $content  = nl2br($_POST['content']);
            $name     = $_FILES['photo1']['name'];
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['photo1,']['tmp_name'];

            $target = '../lifestyle/'.$name;

            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target)) {

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO article (article_title, article_content, photo_1, photo_2) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
                $stmt->execute(array($title,$content,$name,));
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit();

            }

        }

        ?>



<form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
    <<input type="text" name="title" id="title"/>
    <textarea name="content"></textarea></dt>
    <input type="file" name="photo1" >
    <input type="submit" id="add article"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use attribute `multiple` and make some sort of array of the name:

```
<input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple >
```

OR

```
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: Wouldn't it be more clear if photo1[] were just photo[] ? (Because every photo is not photo1) Your question is good though :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Thanks to specify my mistake

Comment: the 'multiple' attribute works only in HTML5 browsers. e.g. IE 10 so it wont work in lower versions

Comment: If I dont name it photo1 and just put it down on the form as "photo[]" will it be written to the database individually?